# Why doesn't jQuery fire the 'input' event on $.val('') input set

Tags: jquery

Why doesn't the `input` event get fired when I changed a text input's value via jQuery.val('')?

http://jsfiddle.net/EC85C/2/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input

Comment: any of the events like change, blur, input etc are fired only when a direct user action causes that change

Comment: Even't aren't fired by jQuery. It's the browser you're using that doesn't have support for the `input` event

Comment: You need to trigger that change: `$('.selector').trigger('change');` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you're trying to get AngularJS to see your changes (via bindings) when you change the value of your input (through jQuery's `val` method)?

I've thrown together this fiddle to illustrate how to get this to work:
http://jsfiddle.net/6JTDf/1/

Instead of calling `trigger` (which creates a jQuery 'event'), you can create a synthetic UIEvent (in our case, 'input'), and then dispatch that on the element. This synthetic event will trigger both the event listener (hello alert!), and the angular binding.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it's just a pitfall in using jquery plugins with angular hu? I figured there should/would be more support since jquery actually does have quite a few legit libraries. If I want to use jquery libraries in the future for this sort of thing, am I really always going to have to edit the plugin so that it also fires the input event in order to update the model?

Comment: I think you're right about the pitfall. I'm guessing there's an "Angular" way of updating the value programmatically, which in turn updates the model as well. I've read articles where they warn against using jQuery outside of Angular, probably for this reason. Good luck!